# Ubuntu/Apache2/ Forbidden/Permission error

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, lamp

I have Ubuntu 11.10 with Lamp installed

There is some files that i can't access to from my web directory "/var/www"

http://localhost/banner/banner.html
I am getting an error :

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /banner/banner.html on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I can access /var/www/index.php normally as i can browse /var/www/banner normally too from my browser

This is a small peace of :

```
    a1a4a@A1A4a:~$ ls -l /var/www
    total 7088
    -rwxrwxrwx  1 root root     916 2011-11-25 20:49 access-controlled.php
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   22163 2011-12-16 22:28 account_info.php
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   22126 2011-12-16 22:27 account_info.php~
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   16585 2011-12-16 21:32 acount_info.php
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root       0 2011-12-16 21:28 acount_info.php~
    drwxrwxrwx  5 root root    4096 2011-12-09 23:03 banner
    drwxrwxrwx  2 root root    4096 2011-12-09 23:03 css
```

And

```
    a1a4a@A1A4a:~$ ls -l /var/www/banner
    total 20
    -rw--w---- 1 root root 2564 2011-11-25 20:51 banner.html
    drwx-w---- 4 root root 4096 2011-12-09 23:03 examples
    drwx-w---- 2 root root 4096 2011-12-09 23:03 lib
    drwx-w---- 4 root root 4096 2011-12-09 23:03 skins
    -rw--w---- 1 root root 1431 2011-11-25 20:51 style.css
```

This is my config :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
```

My "nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf" is set as default ...

How can i make all my /var/www files (folders and sub-folders and files ) accessible from my browser as if i was on a windows machine using Wamp ...

P.S: I will host the website on a Windows machine i am using ubuntu just for coding.

Answer (score 3):

the user running the apache deamon, on ubuntu thats www-data (like in most debian based systems), needs at least read permissions for the files.
But as you posted only owner `root` and group `root` has read rights.

Actually owner `root` has `rw` group `root` has `r`.

So the user actually running the webserver (www-data) falls to the others permissions, which have none.

Either do a `chmod -R o+r /var/www/banner/*` or a `chown -R www-data /var/www/banner` to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

I always forget that while the sub-directories and files need the read permission, the sub-directories also need execute permission.

```
chmod a+x banner
```

This tends to come up when I've saved a web page in the 'Webpage, Complete' format with Chrome or Firefox and am then trying to serve it under localhost, which I often do when building mockups for clients.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is an issue with your `banner.html` permissions - apache`s user has no permissions even to read it.