# Server not picking up the css file

Tags: php, html, css, apache, lampp

I am using lampp for linux.I have saved my homepage home.php inside the htdocs folder.Htdocs folder also contain the css folder in which the css files are present.A snippet of my home.php file looks like.
(It only contains html code,php is still to be embedded.)

```
<html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>KIET,Ghaziabad</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_300.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Myriad_Pro_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie_png.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">ie_png.fix('.png, footer, header nav ul li a, .nav-bg, .list li img');</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="page1">
<!-- START PAGE SOURCE -->
<div class="wrap">
  <header>
 :
 :
 :
 </html>
```

Can anyone tell me the problem.

Comment: add full http path location

Comment: When you load this page in a browser, use the browser's debugging tools to monitor the page resource requests.  What is the requested URL and server response for the CSS files?

Comment: @Sundar:But why?The css folder is in the same directory where home.php is located.It should work.

Comment: use firebug to investigate the css file path.. everything is in proper place

Comment: @David :The mozilla firefox on pressing control-U shows `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">`

Comment: @InsaneCoder: Yes, but what about the actual request to the server and the server's response?  In FireFox, use something like FireBug to monitor the network requests when the page loads.

Comment: @David:I have installed firebug but it isn't showing anything , not even html.Can it be due to the reason that file is saved with php extension?

Comment: Check the `net` tab, and you can see all the files being requested.

Comment: @NickR:There is nothing visible when i click the net tab.

Comment: Open net tab, and then reload your page.

Comment: @CBroe :Yes I can see the files .The path for css file is `http://localhost/css/style.css`

Comment: And the server's response is ...?

Comment: @CBroe:It says `403 Forbidden`

Comment: Then you have a permission error, that's why it's not loading.

Comment: @NickR:What can I do solve this?

Comment: Give the `www-data` user read access to that folder - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8558803/2470724

Comment: Look into the servers error log to see _why_ this request results in a 403. (And don't you dare ask now where to find the error log ...)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have two html tags at the beginning. You only need one.