# Access forbidden in linux mint for apache localhost

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I am doing PHP development using Linux OS ,Lampp Apache server.I changed the default root folder htdocs to another folder `PHP` on my desktop. `When I create a hello.php file in the folder ,I can see it in browser and works well`.
But I have another folder inside this root folder called 'front_end'.When I try to see it in browser using `http://localhost/front_end` ,i get `access forbidden`.
Firebug shows 'Access forbidden'
How can I get access to this folder using localhost?

Another user asked a similar question on stackoverflow ,but it didn't help.

[Ubuntu/Apache2/ Forbidden/Permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558706/ubuntu-apache2-forbidden-permission-error/8558803#8558803)

Comment: check the permission of the folder and your file

Comment: How can i do it in terminal?I am not much experienced in linux commands

Comment: u goto the `DocumentRoot` and do `sudo chown apache:apache index.php`

Comment: to check permissions do `ls -l /path/to/directory`

Comment: Please see the edited code .It specifies the problem more clearly

Comment: `sudo chown apache:apache front_end`

Comment: `sudo chown apache:apache front_end` it says invalid user.My username:groupname is naveen:naveen.When i used this ,it says `front_end` ,no such file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have followed the advice regarding the file permissions.

Have you got an index.php file in the `front_end` directory?

If not that may be why you get 'Access forbidden'. See [Apache 403 Forbidden Error and Solution](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/) Try accessing the spesific php file in the directory e.g. `/front_end/test.php`

Answer (score -2):

## Permissions on the folder

Check the permissions of the folder. 
Use `sudo` to create the folders.

Comment: using sudo to create folders will make it even worse.

Comment: then you must be running your webserver as root. good luck with that

Comment: no that's starting the process as root, but when the server runs its running under a specific user, by default its either apache or httpd

Comment: Oh, so I had some problems with the installation then.